# Agregar valor a un array dentro de un foreach

Tags: php, array, foreach

Buen día.
Quisiera saber como puedo ir agregando los valores obtenidos en un foreach a un array que tiene keys,

creo el array asi:

```
$items = array('id' => 0,'maximo' => 0, 'action' => $inventory );
```

lo que quiero es que un foreach (independiente a esa variable) poder asignarle datos con todo y sus key, algo similar a esto

```
foreach($productos as $key=>$product){
 $maximo[$key] += 1;

 //AQUI COMO AGREGARIA EL VALOR DE $maximo[$key] AL $items    

$maximo[$key] =0;
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué es `$maximo`? ¿Qué es `$productos`? Se agradece un ejemplo basado en código funcional para poder hacer pruebas.

Comment: hmm digamos que $productos es una busqueda a la base de datos donde trae todos los productos, y $maximo seria como un dato que quiero agregar al array

Comment: Bien, has dicho que el array es este: `$items = array('id' => 0,'minimo' => 0, 'action' => $inventory );` y que querrías agregar `$maximo` a ese array. La pregunta es: ¿en qué parte de `$items` quieres agregar el valor de `$maximo`?

Comment: perdon, fue error de tipeo, $minimo es el nombre de la variable correcta, y se agrega al 'minimo'

Comment: No se entiende nada. Por favor pulsa en [edit] y aclara lo que haya que aclarar.

Comment: Intuyo que lo que quieres es ir aumentando `1` al valor de la clave llamada `minimo` del array `$items`. Si es eso, deberías explicarlo así de sencillo. Luego, esto no se entiende nada: `$maximo[$key] += 1;` ¿Qué es lo que pretendes ahí? Por favor, agrega un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable de tu código. Es complicado resolver un problema partiendo de suposiciones y teniendo que adivinar la mayoría de las cosas.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas usar `&` en el `foreach` para poder modificarlo, en tu ejemplo sería algo como esto:

```
foreach($productos as &$product){
   $producto['maximo'] = 123; //por ejemplo
}
```

Puedes ver también:
[ésta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10121508)

Documentación foreach: [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)